# Linear mapping from $P_3 (\mathbb{R})$ to $M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having some trouble understanding base concepts of linear algebra. One of them are linear mappings, or to be precise, linear mapping matrices. 
For example, If the linear mapping $\phi$ is defined as:

$$\phi:P_3 (\mathbb{R}) \to M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})  $$
so that
$$\phi(a+ bx + cx^3 + dx^3) = \begin{bmatrix} a+c+2d & 2a-3b+c+4d \\ b+2c-d & -a +4b + c -3d  \end{bmatrix}$$

I want to find linear mapping matrix in standard basis i.e. $B = \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. 
I began by applying the linear mapping defined on each base vector, thug getting
$$\phi (1) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\phi (x) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -3 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\phi (x^2) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\phi (x^3) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ -1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$$

I understand that this means that all vectors in $im(\phi)$ can be represented as a linear combinations of the above vectors, but how do I form a linear operator matrix? I understand that i could write e.g. 
$$\phi(2x^3 + x^2 - x +1 ) = \alpha  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} + \beta  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -3 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix} + \gamma  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \delta \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ -1 & -3 \end{bmatrix} $$ with $\alpha , \beta, \gamma, \delta $ being scalars from $\mathbb{R}$ but i still can't solve this, let alone form the mapping matrix. 
I even tried the following: 
Let $\chi $ be an isomorphic mapping to $\phi$, such that :
 $$\chi:P_3 (\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^4  $$ 
In this case, i can form the matrix, but how does that matrix relate to the original mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to write the linear map as a matrix you need to fix bases of the two vector spaces, the domain and the target.

As you rightly said, the monomials $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ make up a basis of the space $P_3(\Bbb R)$ but you also need to fix also a basis for the space $M_{2,2}(\Bbb R)$. A standard choice for that is to take the $4$ matrices
$$
e_{i,j}=(a_{k,\ell})\quad\text{where $a_{k,\ell}=1$ if $k=i$, $\ell=j$ and $a_{k,\ell}=0$ otherwise}.
$$
With this choice you have
$$
\phi(1)=1e_{1,1}+2e_{1,2}+0e_{2,1}-1e_{2,2}
$$
and so on. You can now write the matrix associated to $\phi$ in the usual way, i.e. inserting in the $i$-th column the coefficients of $\phi(x^{i-1})$ in its expansion in terms of the basis $\{e_{i,j}\}$. So the entries in the first column are $1$, $2$, $0$, $-1$.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Clears up everything in my head. Thanks!